# How to generate user profile in sub domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I try when user register on my site its profile open in subdomain

right now profile path is

mywebsite.com/page.php?usname=username

I want to convert this in to

username.mywebsite.com

I try various method given here but none of the work for me

I added *.mywebsite.com in DNS zone a record

and use this in my .htaccess

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ page.php?usname=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mywebsite.com
RewriteRule (.*) page.php?usname=%1
```

this code not redirect to username.mywebsite.com

hope some give idea how to correct this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} usname=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^page.php$ http://%1.mywebsite.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?usname=%1
```